# Coding Markdown With a Floating Image

Tags: markdown

I am using [MDwiki](http://dynalon.github.io/mdwiki/#!index.md) to render the markdown in my user documentation.   I would like to add images that float to the right.   So I have the following in my markdown:

```
Test test test.

<img src="/UserGuide/pictures/Dashboard.png" alt="DashBoard" 
     style="float: right; max-width: 50%;"></img>

Next next next.
```

So I get the image and it scales properly and also is right adjusted on the screen properly but the text appears only above and below it and not to the left of it.  Is there something else to add?

I am using an HTML **img** tag instead of the markdown `![txt](x.png)` structure because I could not figure any way to apply those styles.

This might be a problem with MDwiki wizardry.  I notice that it does process the **img** tag such that it is clickable for a magnified view.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone who was where I was:

This works:

```
<p style="max-width: 50%; float: right;">
![Alt Picture Text](something.png "The Caption Of Something")
</p>
```

MDwiki uses a **p** tag as a container for its image structure, so the CSS in the question above doesn't affect it.  So this creates a container around the container, and MDwiki does parse the text inside.